# Cannot specify link libraries for target error CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake

My Cmake is giving me the following error:

```
CMake Error at ros_halcon_bridge/CMakeLists.txt:21 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "treshhold," which is not built by
  this project.
```

And my Cmake file looks like:

```
add_executable(treshhold src/main.cpp)
add_dependencies(treshhold ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(treshhold ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries(treshhold ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

include_directories(/opt/halcon/lib/x64-linux)
target_link_libraries(treshhold, hAcqArgos3D-P1xx.so)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think the problem is the `,` after the `treshhold,`. Try:

```
target_link_libraries(treshhold hAcqArgos3D-P1xx.so)
```

Comment: that brought me to the next error, but fixed the current! thanks!

Comment: Could you then, accept the answer as the right one, not only upvote it? Thanks!

Comment: i was going to but i had to wait a couple of minutes